# Missing Google Play Services in SDK Manager

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I want to use Google Maps in my app. I want to install Google Play Services in the SDK Manager, but when I go to the SDK Manager, I don't see Google Play Services! Why? How can I install this? Can I install this independently of the SDK Manager?

I searched, but I could not find a solution for this.

I see these in Extras:

1. Android Support Library
2. Google AdMob Ads SDK
3. Google Analytics SDK
4. Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library
5. Google Play Billing Library
6. Google Play Licensing Library
7. Google Play APK Expansion Library
8. Google USB Driver
9. Google Web Driver
10. Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download the new SDK here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and start the SDK Manager. Then you will find the Google Play Services.

Afterwards, update the ADT inside Eclipse and you are ready to go!

Old post:

If you want to use Google Maps API in your app, you have to download the Google API in the Android SDK.

Open the SDK, open the newest Android API "folder" (Android 4.4), check Google API's and download it. After that, open the project properties in Eclipse and choose Android. In "Project Build Target" choose Google APIs with API Level 19.

Then you can use the Google Maps Activities etc.

Be sure to use the newest Android SDK Manager, i have currently revision 22.3.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have android sdk 20.0.3 version. I searched in the internet, they say, window-> android SDK Manager-> Extras->Google Play services. but i have not this . why? becuase my version of SDk?  When i go to properties of my project, i can select Google API 16 or lesser. Is this enough?

Comment: Download the newest SDK here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html After this you can select API level 19. Why do you want play services for Google Maps? These are for games and provide achivements, ranks etc.

Comment: Should i update ADT before update SDK?I want show a map in my screen and for this, i want google play services. for this, i should have this? Do i think true?

Comment: No this is not what you do, Google API's are the deprecated v1 google maps not v2. you probably need to update your SDK and ADV in eclipse

Comment: I know google api is deprecated now but i question is: when i update ADT and SDK, can i use google map (i mean "google play services")?

Comment: ah, didn't know that this is depricated. Then just update the SDK and ADT, after this you can install the play services and use the new Google Maps API. Answer edited.

Answer (score 11):

No need to again download the SDK Manager as suggested earlier.

Open SDK Manager>Tools>Manage-add-ons sites>User Defined Sites>New

In New, copy the given links one by one and you'll get it.

link 1->http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

link 2->https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

the same way I got my solution.

Answer (score 7):

You may need to update:

- Android SDK Tools (Rev 22.3)
- Android SDK Platform-tools (Rev 19)
- ADT Plugin (Version: 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826) (If you are using Eclipse)

The first 2 can be updated through the SDK Manager. The ADT Plugin can be updated through the Eclipse update manager (Help -> Check for Updates).

**Edit**

There isn't any special order to make the update. However, ADT Plugin and Android SDK Tools must have the same version. In this case, 22.3 is today's last version (1st of December 2013).

Answer (score 4):

In the SDK manager check the **extras** checkbox and if only 2 options under the same appear like **android support lib** and **Emulator accelerator** check them also.Then check **tools** and under that check only **android sdk tools** and **android sdk platform tools**. Install the checked packages. after that again, reload your SDK manager to see Google Play services appear under the extras. WORKED FOR ME!

Answer (score 3):

**Try launching the SDK Manager by double-clicking the executable** (in my case found at C:\DownloadPath\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\SDK Manager.exe) rather than launching it from Eclipse !!