# Display Google Maps on second screen of Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I know how to launch a new activity within my application, i.e. like continuing to a new screen. In my app when I continue to next screen I would like to display google maps. I can display google maps fine on a one screen application. I'm not sure how to go about this, any help would be greatly appreciated, a the moment it crashes when I try to launch the new activity. 
MainActivity class->

```
package com.example.drivetext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View arg0) {
       // here i call new screen;
       Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, setdestination.class);
       startActivity(i);
       } 
    });

}
}
```

setdestination class->

```
package com.example.drivetext;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


public class setdestination extends Activity {
   static final LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21 , 57);
   private GoogleMap googleMap;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.setdestination);
      try { 
            if (googleMap == null) {
               googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
               findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
         googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
         Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
         position(TutorialsPoint).title("TutorialsPoint"));

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

}
```

Android Manifest->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.drivetext"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.drivetext.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="12"
  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<permission
  android:name="com.example.drivetext.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true" />


<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <activity
     android:name="com.example.drivetext.MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name=".setdestination" android:label="SetDestination"> </activity>


<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="AIzaSyC4VQ7nzxjPSjfObnnKqZxMZUOHACNNmP0" />

   </application>

</manifest>
```

setdestination.xml->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat output->

```
05-02 19:30:37.274: D/gralloc_goldfish(1443): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-02 19:30:40.134: I/Choreographer(1443): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 19:30:40.894: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:40.904: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:40.904: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:40.974: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:40.984: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:41.044: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:41.084: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:41.094: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:41.104: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:41.194: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:41.234: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1443): Google Play services is missing.
05-02 19:30:41.234: D/AndroidRuntime(1443): Shutting down VM
05-02 19:30:41.234: W/dalvikvm(1443): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ac5ba8)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443): Process: com.example.drivetext, PID: 1443
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.drivetext/com.example.drivetext.setdestination}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at com.example.drivetext.setdestination.onCreate(setdestination.java:20)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-02 19:30:41.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1443):     ... 11 more
05-02 19:30:44.104: I/Process(1443): Sending signal. PID: 1443 SIG: 9
05-02 19:49:25.004: D/gralloc_goldfish(1497): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-02 19:49:27.224: I/Choreographer(1497): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 19:49:27.904: W/System.err(1497): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 19:49:27.904: W/System.err(1497):     at com.example.drivetext.setdestination.onCreate(setdestination.java:22)
05-02 19:49:27.914: W/System.err(1497):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-02 19:49:27.914: W/System.err(1497):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-02 19:49:27.914: W/System.err(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-02 19:49:27.914: W/System.err(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-02 19:49:27.914: W/System.err(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-02 19:49:27.914: W/System.err(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-02 19:49:27.914: W/System.err(1497):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-02 19:49:27.914: W/System.err(1497):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-02 19:49:27.914: W/System.err(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-02 19:49:27.944: W/System.err(1497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 19:49:27.944: W/System.err(1497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-02 19:49:27.944: W/System.err(1497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-02 19:49:27.964: W/System.err(1497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-02 19:49:27.964: W/System.err(1497):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 19:49:28.594: I/Choreographer(1497): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 19:50:41.204: I/Choreographer(1497): Skipped 280 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 19:50:42.324: I/Choreographer(1497): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 19:50:46.424: I/Choreographer(1497): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 19:51:25.034: D/gralloc_goldfish(1554): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-02 19:51:27.894: D/AndroidRuntime(1554): Shutting down VM
05-02 19:51:27.904: W/dalvikvm(1554): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ac5ba8)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): Process: com.example.drivetext, PID: 1554
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.drivetext/com.example.drivetext.setdestination}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.example.drivetext.setdestination.onCreate(setdestination.java:18)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     ... 11 more
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.B(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.A(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.gW(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
05-02 19:51:28.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     ... 21 more
05-02 19:51:32.334: I/Process(1554): Sending signal. PID: 1554 SIG: 9
05-02 19:54:42.454: D/gralloc_goldfish(1606): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-02 19:54:51.254: I/Choreographer(1606): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 19:54:51.924: D/AndroidRuntime(1606): Shutting down VM
05-02 19:54:51.924: W/dalvikvm(1606): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ac5ba8)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606): Process: com.example.drivetext, PID: 1606
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.drivetext/com.example.drivetext.setdestination}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.example.drivetext.setdestination.onCreate(setdestination.java:18)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     ... 11 more
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.B(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.A(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.gW(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
05-02 19:54:52.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     ... 21 more
05-02 19:54:55.424: I/Process(1606): Sending signal. PID: 1606 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What does your LogCat say, if anything?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example,drivetext, PID:1443
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.drivetext/com.example.drivetext.setdestination}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: and your setdestination.xml

Answer (score 0):

The Error means that your current emulator is does not support Goolgle Play Service

[Click here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager) on how to update your emulator to support google service

Answer (score 0):

You missed out `<meta-data>` in your Android Manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Try adding this..