# missing google play service in extras folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i want Google play service for Google map in my app but there is missing Google play service in extra folder. even there is no Google folder within the extra folder. can anyone suggest me what should be done to integrate Google play service within my app.I have tried to download and install it but didn't work.And stack over flow isn't letting me to upload the image of my Software development kit manager as i don't have earned 10 points....

so please can anyone help me...thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you gone through all steps.for ref go to this http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/

Comment: click on your sdk and see wheather google play services is installed or not

Comment: You can put the link to the screenshot here and let someone integrate it to your post. Also, you should find "Extras" folder inside the SDK manager. Install "Google Play services" first from that folder.

Comment: there is no google play service installed in SDK manager...and stackoverflow isn't allowing me to put the screen shot here...tgis is being problem plz can anyone..!!

Comment: I think this will help you...

click here->
[Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager

Answer (score 0):

Google folder will not show in extras folder untill you installed google play services.After Google play services installation it will automatically shown in extras folder.

Comment: there is no google play service neither in extras folder nor in SDK manager...from where can i install google play service?? plz suggest me ..it an emergency

Comment: You need to download google play services library from SDK manager. It is listed in bottom most section of SDK list.

Comment: if Google Play services is not present in sdk then update revision. after updation you can see Google play services in sdk manager.

Comment: i updated revision google play service appear...but now every projects contains error...even my completed projects contains error...and eclipse isn't letting me create new project...i have even updated ADT plugin...but nthg happens...what to do know..?

Comment: Right click on project->Properties->Android->select updated API version.

Answer (score 0):

You replace sdk folder by your previous SDK folder and everything will work fine again. Android API level 19 SDK can do this thing for you.