# Can I get Google Play Licensing Library Package back once deleted from SDK Manager?

Tags: java, android

I want to implement App Licensing in my app. As we know, for that we need to install "Google Play Licensing Library" from the Extras Folder of SDK Manager. 
But, i was unable to import the Library Project and the Sample Project, so i deleted that package thinking that re-installation would fix that.

Now My SDK Manager is not showing me that package.

Is there any way to install it back again?

OR i have to get a new SDK.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to you having an old version of the SDK tools.  Try updating your SDK tools and SDK platform tools to the latest version, then close the SDK manager and re-open it.

Another post suggested downloading the latest SDK fresh: [Missing Google Play Services in SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager)