# How can I download Google Play Services in my eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Here is my Android SDK Manager View.

[image]

I want to install Google Play Services as this example.
http://mobiforge.com/design-development/developing-with-google-maps-v2-android

But I didn't find Google Play Services under my Extras folder.

Comment: Try to download the latest version of [adt bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)! and then upgrade the sdk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager/26453071#26453071

above link help me so much for this problem