# My SDK manager does not show Google Play services

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, android-sdk-manager

My Eclipse SDK manager does not show Google Play services.
I want to integrate Google Map in my app, but Google Play services is not showing.

Please help me.
I need it for my college project.

Comment: Tick the check boxes new/updates, installed and obsolete

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing Google Play Services in SDK Manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager)

Comment: i downloaded many updates but still it is not showing google play services. Is i download new sdk manager ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to update following

1. Android SDK Tools
2. Android SDK Platform-tools

It can be updated through SDK manager itself.
For more your can [visit this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking in the Extras folder? 
If it still not there, I recommend that you install the new sdk manager

You can follow the instructions here:
[Missing Google Play Services in SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK Manager in "Extras" at the bottom and make sure you have installed following packages

- Google Play Services
- Google Support Repository
- Google Support Library
- Google Repository