# android sdk doestn't show Google map in extras

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk

[My sdk manager screen :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgYTw.png)

Hi guys i'm trying to add google maps to my android project , but my sdk doestn't show the api of google in extras , what can i do ?

Comment: google maps are not a part of sdk that's why they are not shown there

Comment: thx for the answer , but what can i do to add it ?

Comment: follow this link from start http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: have you seen the picture added to the project ? i Can't find any google api in the extras , the tutorial shows that it must be there ...

Comment: As described in given link it seems you are using older version of sdk . First update that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager